# Highilight a button after pushing javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make simple image gallery with html/css and a bit of javascript.It's all up and working, but one function.

[image: gallery-sorting-images]

I want that when I open the index.html 'All' would be already highlighted by my custom style and if pushed on another button highlight would go to that particular button.

html of a button looks like this

```
<input type='button' value='Design' class="cat-itiem" id='filterDesign'>
```

**edit:** I ended up using [OnResolve's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9267656/1175593) and it worked just fine!(even for someone who doesn't know any JS) Thank you all for help :)

Comment: Use a class of active on it to give it the highlight, then remove it when another is pushed.

Comment: @DVK Before I tried googling to find a suitable example.I've found some, but as I don't know JS yet it was too hard to edit to the level I needed it to work.Now I tried OnResolve's method and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example with jsfiddle for you with simple jQuery. You can see each aspect (markup, css, and jquery).

http://jsfiddle.net/p5ZUv/7/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your highlighted class is called `activeButton`, you could do the following with jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(".cat-itemem").click(function () {
        $(".cat-itemem").removeClass('activeButton');
        $(this).addClass('activeButton');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly append styles on button click via pure css, but to unhighlight others you need javascript.

**HTML:**

```
    <input type='button' value='All' class="cat-itiem highlighted" id='filterAll'>
    <input type='button' value='Design' class="cat-itiem" id='filterDesign'>
    <input type='button' value='Logo' class="cat-itiem" id='filterLogo'>
<input type='button' value='Photography' class="cat-itiem" id='filterPhotography'>
```

**CSS** (Add yours)

```
.cat-itiem{}

.highlighted{background:green}
```

**JS** (Jquery is used)

```
$('.cat-itiem').click(function(){$('.cat-itiem').removeClass('highlighted'); $(this).addClass('highlighted')}
```